# Disconnecting all the connections after certain time of Idleness in HikariCP

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, hikaricp

I am using SpringBoot(2.0.4),Hibernate,Postgres and HikariCP(2.7.9)

I want a configuration in which the pooled connections by HikariCP should be released back to DB after certain amount of being Idle.

For example considering the default configuration of HikariCP in SpringBoot, the pool is initialized with 10 DB Connections.

I want that if there is inactivity for suppose 2 hours all the connections should be return back to DB.

If after 2 hours any request for connections comes, the HikariCP should reinitialize the whole pool of 10 connections and serve it.

Is this possible ? Is there any configuration setting for such requirement ?